# How to put input value in card-title and card-text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm new from scripting world so sorry for my bad factory code. 
I'm trying to make appear the input value in "card title" and "card-text" of my "cards" variable

Here is the code:

```
<input id="input1" class="form-control form-control-lg" type="text" placeholder="Write something" value="">
<input id="input2" class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Write something else" value="">
<button class="btn btn-success" id="create">Create</button>
```

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#create").click(function(){   
      let cards = '<div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">' +
        '<div class="card-body">' + 
        '<h5 class="card-title"></h5>' +
        '<p class="card-text"></p>' +
        '<button class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</button>' +
        '</div>' +
        '</div>';

      $(document.body).append(cards);
    });
  });  
</script>
```

Thanks everyone for the help!

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve that in the way like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#create").click(function() {
        let cards =
            '<div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">' +
            '<div class="card-body">' +
            `<h5 class="card-title">${$('#input1').val()}</h5>` +
            `<p class="card-text">${$('#input2').val()}</p>` +
            '<button class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</button>' +
            "</div>" +
            "</div>";

        $(document.body).append(cards);
    })
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with the following:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#create").click(function() {
    var cardtitle = $('#input1').val();
    var cardtext = $('#input2').val();
    let cards = '<div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">' +
      '<div class="card-body">' +
      '<h5 class="card-title">'+cardtitle+'</h5>' +
      '<p class="card-text">'+cardtext+'</p>' +
      '<button class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</button>' +
      '</div>' +
      '</div>';
    $(document.body).append(cards);
  });
});
```

**Demo**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $("#create").click(function() {
    var cardtitle = $('#input1').val();
    var cardtext = $('#input2').val();
    let cards = '<div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">' +
      '<div class="card-body">' +
      '<h5 class="card-title">'+cardtitle+'</h5>' +
      '<p class="card-text">'+cardtext+'</p>' +
      '<button class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</button>' +
      '</div>' +
      '</div>';

    $(document.body).append(cards);

  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="input1" class="form-control form-control-lg" type="text" placeholder="Write something" value="">


<input id="input2" class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Write something else" value="">


<button class="btn btn-success" id="create">Create</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$("#create").click(function(){   

let cards = '<div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">' +
            '<div class="card-body">' + 
            '<h5 class="card-title">'+ $('#input1').val() +'</h5>' +
            '<p class="card-text">'+ $('#input2').val() +'</p>' +
            '<button class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</button>' +
            '</div>' +
            '</div>';

$(document.body).append(cards);

    });

});
```